# Sawtooth wave spectrum

Tags: signal-processing

The Fourier transform of a periodic signal is a pulse train, but for a sawtooth wave, what is the fundamental frequency of the spectrum?

Thanks

Comment: You heard wrong. A pulse train is it's own Fourier transform. Also, you'll have to reword what you mean by the fundamental frequency of the spectrum. Since the spectrum of a sampled signal repeats every $2\pi$ radians/sample, one might say that is the fundamental frequency of them all.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental frequency is the inverse of the period (if you measure phase in cycles) or $2 \pi$ divided by the period (if you measure in radians).  The Fourier expansion is shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) as $\dfrac 2\pi\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac {\sin(2k\pi f t)}k$

Comment: Thanks, but I think you are explaining the fourier series not the fourier transform.

Comment: For a periodic function, they are the same.  There is only energy at harmonics of the period.

Comment: Thanks, it's true. In a fourier series, the non-integer samples are always zero.